# angular dialog within feature module throws error 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I put together a very basic scenario:
an angular app that contains a module that contains a dialog. If I compile this app, it compiles successfully, but then throws the above error. However, the application runs correctly and opens the dialog correctly.
My app module:

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogBodyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MyDlgModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My feature module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DlgManagerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    DlgManagerComponent]
})
export class MyDlgModule { }
```

I know that in pre 9 versions this error was caused by not adding the dialog to the entryComponents, but this is according to help not any more needed (and even if i do it, the error still comes up).

The output of the compiler is as follows:

```
 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 25.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 431ms
: Compiled successfully.
    
    ERROR in src/app/my-dlg/dialogInModule/dialogInModule.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-dialog-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-dialog-content' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    
    3 <mat-dialog-content>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/my-dlg/dialogInModule/dialogInModule.component.ts:6:16
        6   templateUrl: './dialogInModule.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component DialogInModuleComponent.
```

Can anybody help here? Or is this a bug?
Iam using Version 10.1.2 of Angular and 10.2.1 of angular/material

Comment: Your component name in the error log (`DialogInModuleComponent`) isn't the same as the declared component name (`DlgManagerComponent`) in your featured module.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Edric, I forgot to also add the DialogInModuleComponent to the Declarations Array!